# Forcing reload always on a has_one/belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
    has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
.
.
end
```

and

```
class UserMilaapDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
    belongs_to :user
.
.
end
```

So I need to get the copy of `Profile` from DB and not from cache when I do user.profile automatically without doing `user.profile(true)`. Can I achieve do it while specifying association? If not what is the alternative?

Comment: look into this http://railspikes.com/2008/8/18/disabling-activerecord-query-caching-when-needed

Answer (score 2):

Per https://coderwall.com/p/zifrrw/clear-cache-of-a-ruby-on-rails-association it looks like you have the option of calling #reset on the association to clear it for the next invocation, but it sounds like that is not what is desired.

I'm not aware of an easy way to get rails itself to disable caching permanently for a single association.

I think the best approach is to create another method that can be called to wrap this behavior.

```
def uncached_profile
    profile(true)
end
```

If you want to retain the object's outfacing profile method, you could use alias_method_chain to redefine #profile:

```
def profile_with_no_caching(reload = true)
   profile_without_no_caching(reload)
end
alias_method_chain :profile, :no_caching
```

Comment: This won't work as has_one and belongs_to associations will not return an ActiveRecord::Relation object, which is what #reset is defined on.  You'll end up calling #reset on the returned ActiveRecord::Base object instance resulting in a NoMethodError.